# Exception Handling in JSP with Beans

Tags: jsp, exception, servlets, javabeans

I'm looking for a good way to handle exceptions in my JSP page.
So I have a JSP page where I access my beans getters like :

```
<c:when test="${exampleBean.metric.outOfDate}">
    <div class="OutOfDate">Out of Date</div>
</c:when>
 ... and so on
```

So when I access exampleBean.metric, it believe it goes to a getMetric method in my metricBean. This metric however may not exist and so I throw an error from there by just going

```
public Metric getMetric() throws Exception1, Exception2{
 // the names of the Exceptions are just dummies here
 try {
       // to do some invalid stufff
    } catch (Exception1 ex) {
        throw ex;
    } catch (Exception2 ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

So, I call this bean getter method multiple times for a single page and it sometimes fails for a few, I want to know what the error was thrown in my JSP to display it to a user.

I know the method of having a custom error page in my web.xml file where I make all throws go to a single error page, but I don't want that, since its possible for a small portion of the page to be causing an error, and I want the rest of the page to still be shown

Am I handling this an incorrect way? ie the error checking should be somehow done in my servlet or somewhere else? If so how would I be able to check my bean methods there? Any links would be appreciated

Using JSTL  methods haven't helped me either ie I tried encapsulating the thing with a catch like so :

```
<c:catch var="exception">
   <c:when test="${exampleBean.metric.outOfDate}">
      <div class="OutOfDate">Out of Date!</div>
   </c:when>
</c:catch>
<c:if test="${exception!=null}">
     <%-- give a user message saying something was wrong, but this didn't give an exception even when it was called from my bean--%>
</c:if>
```

Comment: Are you sure there was an exception thrown. Can you try a simple test code from [this link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_catch_tag.htm) in your JSP, to check if the page is being called and the ELs and other stuff is working fine? Thanks

Comment: Actually, today it seems to catch the exception in the JSTL statement once its thrown in the bean -.- urgh. So would using JSTL to catch these errors thrown in the bean be the best way to go?

Comment: I don't generally catch exceptions in a JSP. Atleast I till now I have not got any case were I had to. But if you absolutely know what exceptions would be thrown from the bean then I guess you can go this way.